# What encoding is this extended ASCII a part of?

Tags: php, ascii, extended-ascii

What encoding is this extended ASCII a part of:

[image: Extended ASCII]

I always thought this was [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), but as I was dealing with CP-1252 strings today, I realized that they are different. This is linked from the [PHP chr page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php), but if I output the extended ASCII characters:

```
for ($i = 128; $i < 256; $i++) echo chr($i);
```

I get this:

```
€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ
```

And if it isn't a [supported PHP encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php), then it shouldn't be linked from the PHP website.

Comment: Have you tried UTF-8 ?

Comment: I love cowards who -1 without a comment.

Comment: I know the feeling. Well my friend, it wasn't me, I can assure you of that.

Comment: Fred, it cannot be UTF-8: This is a single-byte extended ASCII encoding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to come straight from [Code Page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. I clicked a bunch of the "Windows codepages" on [this template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Character_encoding), but I didn't think to click the DOS codepages. I'll have to submit a PHP documentation bug for linking an unsupported encoding.